# $_COOKIE global var encoding

Tags: php, cookies, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I know, I should not use ISO-8859-1 however I have this website that was handled to me and it will be impossible to migrate all PHP/JS/HTML to use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1.

My problem is this: this website uses `encodeURIComponent` to store values in cookies with Javascript. For example,in the `index.html` file (which uses `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`) there is a `<script>` tag with this code within:

```
document.cookie = "xxx=" + encodeURIComponent("não") + ";.....";
```

The cookie value gets stored as `n%C3%A3o` (I checked the Dev Tools on Chrome in Application tab). Despite the HTML file is ISO, the cookie is saved as UTF-8. Great! That's exactly how `encodeURIComponent` works, it will always convert it to UTF-8.

The problem comes when PHP pages use this `xxx` cookie value to do some stuff. Since all PHP files were saved as ISO-8859-1, when it tries to access `$_COOKIE["xxx"]` problems start to happen like chars being corrupted.

Clearly I must use `utf8_decode($_COOKIE["xxx"])` to fix this problem cause it gets the cookie value and parses it to ISO-8859-1.

The problem is that this website has hundreds of PHP files which uses cookies all over the place. Changing all lines of code would require lots of time - which I dont have since my boss wants this problem solved for today.

So here comes my question:

1) how does PHP knows the cookie should be read as UTF-8 and assign a UTF-8 encoding to $_COOKIE ? When I access $_COOKIE it clearly already decoded the cookie value cause the `%xx` were already decoded. I know you could say `Of course you dumb, cookies are all the time stored as UTF-8.`. But this is not always true.

If inside of a PHP file (which was saved using ISO-8859-1 encoding) I do this:

```
setcookie("xxx","não");
```

When I inspect the cookie (in Chrome Dev Tools -> Application tab) it shows `n%E3o`.

You see? `n%E3o` is different of `n%C3%A3o`.

So, when parsing the cookie, how does PHP know that `n%E3o` should be decoded as ISO-8859-1 and how does PHP know that `n%C3%A3o` should be decoded as UTF-8?

I know that `_GET`, `_POST`, `_COOKIE` super global variables are automatically decoded by PHP. But how does it know the source charset and how does it decide which charset to output?

Comment: I would give a try using mb_convert_encoding.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: @Alex That's basically the same as `utf8_decode()` here. This is one of the rare cases when such function is being used in the right context :)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I just overlooked it.

Comment: It's possible that a global search to replace `encodeURIComponent()` with its legacy equivalent `escape()` does the trick. Existing cookies will be lost, but surely this issue that needs to be fixed today has been happening for years ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't really "know" much about encodings at all. And in this case, it doesn't need to. [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), what's used for cookies, explicitly works at an encoding neutral byte level. Meaning, the encoding itself expresses raw bytes. `%C3%A3` expresses the two bytes `0xC3A3`, which is the UTF-8 encoding for the character "ã". Or it's the encoding for the characters "Ã£" if you read them as ISO-8859-1. So PHP just decodes the percent encoding to raw bytes; what characters that ends up being depends on what you interpret them with. PHP doesn't interpret them at all, PHP strings are just raw byte arrays.

Conversely, any string literal in PHP source code files just is, again, a raw byte array whose content depends on the encoding the source code file is saved in. In a PHP file saved as ISO-8859-1, the string literal `"não"` contains the bytes `0x6EF16F`. The same file stored as UTF-8 contains the bytes `0x6EC3A36F`. In percent encoding, those raw bytes are simply encoded as is.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for more details on the topic.

Comment: Ok but I think there is something missing. In latest versions of PHP, functions like `htmlentities` (and many others) now demand you to set a charset otherwise UTF8 will be the default. However, with `setcookie` function there is no option to inform the charset, and for some reason PHP is using ISO-8859-1 in the example I posted to you. Why isnt it using UTF-8 by default? Also, setcookie has no way to know the encoding of my srtring, as you own said, it's just bare bytes.

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's just raw bytes, that's why `setcookie` doesn't need to know what encoding it is. The PHP string is the raw bytes from the raw file, however it was saved. `setcookie` encodes the raw bytes to "percentage encoded raw bytes". At no point does PHP need to be aware of what the encoding actually is, because it doesn't treat the string as characters nor does it interpret the characters or convert the encoding.

Comment: `htmlentities()` is different because it's a text manipulation function and it needs to identify e.g. `é` to convert it to `&eacute;`. Cookie functions don't need to know the encoding because they won't do anything with it.